# Why are bases corrosive?

Tags: acid-base, corrosion

If I understand correctly, an acid corrodes things because the hydronium ion attracts electrons away from whatever it is reacting with.  Do bases corrode things in a similar manner? with the metal cation operating in the same way as the hydronium ion (taking electrons)?

Comment: Note that NaCl is corrosive too.

Comment: "Corrosion is a natural process that converts a refined metal into a more chemically stable oxide. [....] In the most common use of the word, this means electrochemical oxidation of metal in reaction with an oxidant such as oxygen, hydrogen or hydroxide." from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrosion Not exactly a perfect definition but useful. Starting from definitions is often helpful.

Comment: Check difference between acidic corrosion and alkaline corrosion: https://tft-pneumatic.com/blog/corrosion-under-acidic-alkaline-conditions/

Answer (score 6):

It depends on *what* is being corroded.

- Alkalis are *caustic*, because they saponify fats in skin, changing a fatty acid to soap.
- Some bases are strong electrolytes, speeding galvanic corrosion.
- Some metals react with the hydroxyl ion, such as [zinc](https://www.webelements.com/zinc/chemistry.html), forming the zincate ion, $\ce{[Zn(OH)4]^2-}$. The reaction of bases with aluminum is used to make hydrogen on demand, and to clean drains, as [in this product](https://www.whatsinproducts.com/files/brands_pdf/9485_19001436%20MSDS%20Drano_Crystals.pdf).
- Silica, $\ce{SiO2}$, is acidic, and reacts with bases to form silicates. For that reason, $\ce{NaOH}$ should not be stored in glass containers, which are attacked by dissolved $\ce{NaOH}$ (from moisture in air).

Comment: Hydroxide ion not hydroxyl radical. the oxidizer is water. The initial oxidation reaction is probably a one electron transfer to make H , Zn+ and OH- eventually OH- complexes with the Zinc ions to lower their potential and force the reaction. A radical mechanism while feasible on paper seems more complicated since OH-and H2O abound and OH radicals scarce.

Comment: @jimchmst, I stand corrected for my radical misstatement, admittedly at the root of the issue. They wouldn't be unionized (too Marxist for 'em).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik To clean drains full of aluminum? Or with hydrogen? So confusing.

Comment: @PaulKolk, NaOH+ Al is mixed in a common drain cleaner, creating effervescent hydrogen and even *more* heat than created by NaOH dissolving. Reference will be added above.